# How do I repeat a character a specific number of times based on the value of another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

In Google Sheets, cell `A1` contains the number of times the letter "A" should be repeated in cell `B1`

i.e.

If `A1=3` then `B1="A A A"`

My rough script is:

```
for(var arow=0; arow<4; arow++) {
  var numberofo = actsheet.getRange(arow+1,1).getValue();
     for(i=0; i<=numberofo;i++) {
         var test = actsheet.getRange(i+1,2).setValue("o");
     };
 }
```

Sorry the code looks rough. Haven't coded for the last 7 years.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a scripting challenge for yourself? Or are you actually trying to solve a real-world problem. If the latter, you don't need script, just a formula:

`=REPT("A",A1)`

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to return **`A A A`** as opposed to **`AAA`**

```
=JOIN("", REPT("A", A1))
```

or

```
=TRIM(REPT("A ", A1))
```

[JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) [REPT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134?hl=en) [TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en)